# The best way to step down 12V to 5V with at least 10A current from a PS3 power supply for a WS2812B LED strip

Tags: power-supply, buck, step-down, ws2812b

I am new to electronics. I had a PS3 Super Slim power supply lying around, which outputs 12V up to 13 amps. Recently, I bought a 5-meter strip of WS2812B LED strip, which needs 5V, and the recommended current is 10A. Currently, I am using a 12V 3.3A laptop charger and an [MP1584 Step Down Converter Buck Module (5V Fixed Output)](https://quartzcomponents.com/collections/dc-to-dc-converter/products/mp1584-5v-fixed-output-3a-dc-step-down-converter-buck-module) to get 5V output. However, I need more current, and I think the buck converter is limited to 3A. I couldn't find any information related to the maximum output current on the site where I bought it.

So, my question is: What's the best way to step down the 12V from the PS3 power supply to 5V and get at least 10A of current? Or is it even possible?

Comment: Just buy a 5V power supply that can provide 10A. And avoid buying from sites that don't give proper datasheets.

Comment: It would be much easier to buy 12v addressable strips if you intend to use a 12v power supply.

Comment: It's definitely possible. Just look for a DC-DC converter module (or design your own, though that would be hard if you don't have a background in power electronics) that's rated for 10 A or more.